# Merge the tags [windows-live-movie-maker] and [windows-movie-maker]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, tag-synonym-request

[windows-live-movie-maker](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-live-movie-maker) and [windows-movie-maker](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-movie-maker) are the same thing, at least according to the questions.

Shouldn't these two be merged (if possible) / made synonyms?

Comment: The older version uses the `mswmm` file extension while the other uses the `wlmp` file extension. They are not compatible with each other.

Comment: No! They are not the same!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just want to note that the two are not really the same thing.

The Windows Live label was introduced at some point and the Windows Movie Maker got a drastic overhaul, losing features and compatibility in the process. From Wikipedia:

> #### Windows Live
>
> A new version of the software, renamed Windows Live Movie Maker 2009, was released as a beta on September 17, 2008, and officially released as a standalone product through Windows Live Essentials suite on August 19, 2009. This was **effectively completely new software as it could not read projects created by earlier versions and did not support custom XML transitions written for the previous versions. In addition, a great many features were removed.**

Comment: Here's the thing. WLMM is different from pre-WLMM WMM, but recently WLMM was renamed back to WMM, so post-WLMM WMM is still called WMM but different from pre-WLMM WMM. And you get a cookie if you manage to read that without getting a headache.

Comment: Sorry, I never knew that they were actually different. I always thought the 2 were part of the Windows Live 'suite' and over the years it had shortened to WMM. Sorry for the waste of time, should I delete this 'question'?

Comment: Should I remove the 'tag-synonym-request' tag? But keep the question in case future users think this is the same thing, like I did.

Comment: @shub Leave it as it is, it'll make it easier to find it

Comment: Should I add the 'rejected' tag *as well*?

Comment: @shub Only moderators can add that tag

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Told you we should ;)

Comment: @Bob Give me a cookie :)

Answer (score 4):

An interesting thing is, the older versions of WMM are actually not WLMM, which was new and introduced with 7 (and breaks backwards compatibility with the old project files). IIRC, WLMM also has less functionality than WMM. So, they're not really the same thing.

On the other hand, with the release of 8, WLMM was renamed back to WMM - and this new WMM is different from the old XP/Vista-era one. If there's a merge/synonym at all, WLMM should go be merged into WMM, the more general and current name.

Comment: I never knew that. If they're not the same, we shouldn't do anything to the tags then I think

Answer (score 0):

It should just be called movie-maker.

Comment: No, it shouldn't because the two are ***not*** the same (as the other 2 answers say).

Comment: ^Not only that, but having just [movie-maker] makes it a **very** generic tag that is open to misuse on questions unrelated to the Windows Movie Maker (either version)